# ODE with separable variables and three conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, radicals

I have to solve $y^{'}(x)=cos(x)y^{3}(x)$.

Seemingly straightforward, I write $$\displaystyle \int \frac{dy}{y^3}=\int \cos x dx\rightarrow \frac{y^{-3+1}}{-3+1}=\sin x+c$$

$$ -\frac{1}{2}y^{-2}=\sin x+c\rightarrow y^2=\frac{1}{-2(\sin x+c)} \Rightarrow y=\pm \left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{c+\sin x}}
\right)$$

Now the text asks to find the solution "with the initial condition $y(x_0)=y_0$ in the three different cases:

- $y_0=0$
- $y_0>0$
- $y_0<0$

This is the first time i have come across a problem of this nature, i don't know how to solve it. Am i still create the system?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $\cos x$ has to be in the denominator of the integral.

Comment: Gross mistake of distraction... Thanks.

Comment: Correction: the text is right, and also the solution.

Comment: Didn't you divide the initial equation by $y^3$ as well as by $\cos x?$

Comment: The correct text is $y'(x)=cos(x)y^3$, and i'm arrived to this equation. But now, i don't understand how to: 1) eliminate the sign $-$ from $y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{-1}{2(sinx+c)}}$; 2) find the three solutions with the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is real since $y_0$ is real.

- The case $y_0=0$ was solved by @Kavi Rama.

The general non-zero solution verifies $y^2=\frac{-1}{2(\sin x +c)},$ and is real only if $(\sin x + c)$ is negative.

- $y_0>0$ leads to $y_0=\sqrt\frac{-1}{2(\sin 0 +c)}=\sqrt{\frac{-1}{2c}},$ from where $c=-\frac{1}{2{y_0}^2}$ and therefore $y=\sqrt\frac{-1}{2(\sin x -1/(2{y_0}^2))}.$
- Similarly, $y_0<0$ leads to $y_0=-\sqrt{\frac{-1}{2c}}.$ Again, $c=-\frac{1}{2{y_0}^2}$ and $y=-\sqrt\frac{-1}{2(\sin x -1/(2{y_0}^2))}.$

Comment: Thanks Maan for your answer. Can i ask you why $y_0>0$ leads to $y_0=\sqrt{\frac{-1}{2(sin0+c)}}$?

Comment: Because $y_0$ is the value obtained for $x=0.$ From $y^2=\frac{-1}{2(\sin x +c)}$ you get $(y_0)^2=\frac{-1}{2(\sin 0 +c)}$. Then $y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{-1}{2(\sin 0 +c)}}.$

Answer (score 2):

The only solution in the first case is $y=0$. (Because when you assumed that $y \neq 0$ and divided by $y^{3}$ you got a solution which does not satisfy $y_0=0$. Let $f(x)$ be the integral of $\sec x$. For $y_0 >0$ the solution is $\frac 1 {\sqrt 2 \sqrt {c+ f(x)}}$ and For $y_0 <0$ the solution is $-\frac 1 {\sqrt 2 \sqrt {c+f(x)}}.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one question. I obtain this solution $y^2=\frac{-1}{2(sinx+c)}\rightarrow y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{-1}{2(sinx+c)}}$. Now, how can i eliminate the sign $-$ under the square root (because, otherwise, i have complex solutions...). Moreover, WolframAlpha says that the solution is $y=\pm {\frac{1}{\sqrt(2)\sqrt(c-sinx)}}$.

Comment: They are the same solution, since $$ \sqrt{\frac{-1}{2(\sin x + c)}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2(-c-\sin x)}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2(\bar{c}-\sin x)}} $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, if they're equal, how would you answer my question? Kavi Rama Murthy tried to explain it, but i need to see the whole process.